# Transit visa for Germany when going to Finland

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, germany, schengen-visas, finland

Do I need a transit visa as an Indian passport holder for Germany in order to travel to Finland from Dubai?

Dubai - Germany (2hrs stop) - Finland

Provided I will have a Schengen Visa (Finland)?

Comment: See here, first title of the answer: [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Answer (score 3):

No, the Schengen Visa is for the Schengen Area.

You will enter the Schengen Area in Germany and then take an internal flight to Finnland.

Make sure that the Visa is valid when you enter/exit the Schengen Area.
The day you enter and the day of exit count for the 90/180 days rule.

Comment: The partial days also count for the duration of stay if it is less than 90 days.